# Customizer cuistom CSS Priority ordre Issue

Tags: functions, customization, theme-customizer

```
function theme_customizer_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-customizer-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme-customizer.css' );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles', 'theme_customizer_styles' );
```

I created a custom checkbox for the theme customizer, and it has its own unique style. I included the style as shown above, but the problem is that the default WordPress styles are loaded on top, which overrides my custom styles. How can I ensure that my custom CSS files are loaded last in the WordPress admin area and on top?

This is overriding and conflicting ↓

[image]